# Store user sensitive data for both Android and iOS app

Tags: android, iphone, spring-boot, security

We have apps developed for both Android and iOS which interacts with devices via BLE and uses a Spring boot backend server in which they have registered and logged in. They can log in with the same account on either Android or iOS (obviously). During the interaction we can get codes that the user may need in the future. To handle that we currently do this:

- **Android**: Encourage the user to write the code down. Use the users login information (username/password) to generate a symmetric key which is used to encrypt data which is then sent to and stored in our server. That way, only the user can retrieve it and decrypt it. Drawbacks would be the way we generate the key in itself and the obvious fact that a user that has forgotten password/changed password cannot decrypt the data anymore.
- **iOS**: Encourage the user to write the code down. Then store it in KeyChain with the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute so it can sync to iCloud KeyChain. That way the user should be able to get it on any other iOS device. Obvious drawback is that if the user chooses to switch to Android then the code cannot be retrieved there.

Is there anyway we can store `sensitive user app data` for both platforms? We could store it in our server but since we want the users to encrypt it themselves (so we can't see the content of the data) we need some unified way. There is no magic Spring boot feature to store "encrypted user data" for a specific user which only that user can retreive?

Have thought about using `Google Drive` and store it in the hidden app folder. But I'm guessing that wont work with an iOS app that uses the `Google Drive SDK`?

**EDIT**
Just to exemplify:

A user buys the device and connects it to its Android app. The user then changes the `reset code` of the device which is what would be needed if the device was ever "factory reset" (of course not factory, but cleared). When that is done we encourage the user to write this code down/remember it. Then lets say the the user loses the Android phone and buys an iPhone. He logs in to the exact same account but now might need to reset the device in order to start using it again. If that code could have been stored somehow using the account (or using the users google account or anything) then he wouldn't have to remember it.

Comment: in case of password change, is it possible to decrypt data, generate new key (based on the new password) and encrypt data again?

Comment: Android and iOS are distinct platforms. For apps there is nothing in common between both platforms, but some functions are similar. Therefore you have to develop an individual app for each platform and make use of the available security features such as `AndroidKeystore` and iOS `Keychain`.

Comment: Robert: I don't see the point of your comment. Of course they are distinct platforms. And we of course have individual apps for them both. In our case they do however communicate with the same device over BLE and that device can generate the same type of data which we want to securely store. `Keystore` only works locally on a device and Keychain will not work towards android. Hence my question?

Comment: Zeeshan: That would be possible if not for the "Forgot password" feature in which the change is done from a webapp (which has no access to the data).